# Grafana Prometheus wrong default query

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Hi f I have metrics like e`nvoy_cluster_cluster_service1_upstream_rq_time` and  `envoy_cluster_cluster_service2_upstream_rq_time` up to 100 how to sum them all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum({__name__=~"envoy_cluster_cluster_service[0-9]+_upstream_rq_time"})`

Or better yet, [relabel your metrics](https://medium.com/quiq-blog/prometheus-relabeling-tricks-6ae62c56cbda).